# WebSphere administrative role checking within servlet context

Tags: java, security, servlets, websphere, roles

I am simply trying to check whether a given user has a given WebSphere administrative role, within a Java servlet.

The idiom:

```
HttpServletRequest#isUserInRole
```

... works for non-administrative roles, **and** the *iscadmins* administrative role defined in [this](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rsec_adminroles.html) documentation page.

However, all other roles in the page above (which seem to differ from *iscadmins*, scope-aside, by having their first letter capitalized) are not reflected when invoking `isUserInRole`.

I've tried checking both with the primary administrative user (file-based, created with the profile) and with other users whom I've explicitly added administrative roles to.

In all cases, only *iscadmin* role checks return true when assigned.

Using standard WAS 8.5.5 if that's any relevant.

I am wondering whether there is something crucial I misunderstand about security and scope in this context.

**Note**

I have tried different combinations to check for role names that have a first capitalized letter: as is, lowercase, all-caps, etc. even got more creative with the *Admin Security Manager* role...

Answer (score 0):

After hours and hours of headaches and searches through undocumented APIs, I think I've found what I'm looking for.

**Fair warning**

I couldn't find *any* documentation about this, not even javadocs. 
I cannot honestly tell if this is the recommended approach.

This said, the approach below works for me (tested by assigning and removing the *Admin security manager* role from the logged on user, then reloading the servlet and debugging).

Also, the mistery remains on why these roles are not visible through the `HttpServletRequest#isUserInRole` idiom.

**Code recipe**

```
// relevant imports
import com.ibm.websphere.management.authorizer.AdminAuthorizer;
import com.ibm.websphere.management.authorizer.AdminAuthorizerFactory;
import static com.ibm.ws.security.util.Constants.*;

// you'll need the com.ibm.ws.admin.core.jar plugin in your classpath for this
AdminAuthorizer aa = AdminAuthorizerFactory.getAdminAuthorizer();

// all admin roles are there as constants, 
// save for "iscadmins", which you can retrieve with
// the HttpServletRequest#isUserInRole idiom anyway
String role = com.ibm.ws.security.util.Constants.ADMINSECURITY_ROLE;

// that's it!
boolean test = aa.isCallerInRole(role);
```